# Adding checkboxes in a loop - Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have an `agent` model and I am trying to add a check box next to each agent's name so it can be used to search. I am coming up a bit short. Below is the code I currently have, but am not sure how to enter the name. Right now I am just getting a bunch of checkboxes.

html.erb:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-agent-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">Agents <span class="caret"></span></a>

<div id="listing-agent-popover" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <% @agents.each do |agent| %>
            <%= check_box_tag :agent_id_list, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Agent", data: { "binding-name" => "agent_id_list" } %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#listing-agent-selector').popover( {
  html: true,
  trigger: 'manual',
  placement: 'bottom',
  template:  '<div class="popover price-range-pop" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
  content: function() {
    return $('#listing-agent-popover').html();
  }
});
```

search_for.rb:

```
attribute :agent_id_list, String

def agent_ids
  String(agent_id_list).split(',')
    .reject(&:blank?)
end

def agent_id_list_scope
  if agent_ids.empty?
    Listing.all
  else
    Listing.where("listing_agent_id IN (?) OR sales_agent_id IN (?)", agent_ids, agent_ids)
  end
end
```

current result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a look and see if this helps you out a it

What I did was added a row for each agent to display the name next to

```
<a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-agent-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">Agents <span class="caret"></span></a>

<div id="listing-agent-popover" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <% @agents.each do |agent| %>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <%= check_box_tag :agent_id_list, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Agent", data: { "binding-name" => "agent_id_list" } %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
              <%= @agent.name %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the block to look for

```
      <% @agents.each do |agent| %>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <%= check_box_tag :agent_id_list, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Agent", data: { "binding-name" => "agent_id_list" } %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <%= @agent.name %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```